# How to start and initialize Mysql 8 using Docker?

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I keep getting this error: `mysqld: File '/var/lib/mysql/auto.cnf' not found (OS errno 13 - Permission denied)` when building the docker image from my Dockerfile and then running `docker-compose up` using my docker-compose.yml file. I'm using this command to build the docker image `docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64 --load -t mysqltest -f path/to/Dockerfile .` I'm using buildx to build the docker image because i'm running a mac with m1 chip. I want this image to be able to run on an intel machine. Below are the docker files:
Dockerfile:

```
FROM mysql/mysql-server:8.0.32

# needed for intialization
ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=test_password
ENV MYSQL_DATABASE=new_database
ENV MYSQL_USER=user
ENV MYSQL_PASSWORD=test_password

RUN microdnf update && microdnf -y install vim

EXPOSE 3306
CMD ["mysqld"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.7"

networks:
  backend:
    driver: ${NETWORKS_DRIVER}

services:
  
...

  db:
    image: mysqltest
    container_name: db
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./path/to/Dockerfile
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    expose:
      - "3306"
    volumes:
      - db-volume:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./docker/db/sql-scripts:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
      - ./docker/db/configs:/etc/mysql
    networks:
      - backend
...

volumes:
  db-volume:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got this working by commenting out `CMD ["mysqld"]` in the Dockerfile and changing the volumes to a brand new volume in the docker-compose.yml. That looks like:

```
db:/var/lib/mysql
```

I also commented out

```
#      - ./docker/db/sql-scripts:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
#      - ./docker/db/configs:/etc/mysql
```

So here's the final docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3.7"

networks:
  backend:
    driver: ${NETWORKS_DRIVER}

services:
  ...

  db:
    image: mysqltest
    container_name: db
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./path/to/Dockerfile
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    expose:
      - "3306"
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql
#      - ./docker/db/sql-scripts:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
#      - ./docker/db/configs:/etc/mysql
    networks:
      - backend
...

volumes:
  db:
```